# Does Apple require HTTPS from iOS Apps? 2018 Version

Tags: ios, https

As in the subject, does Apple today, require HTTPS for calls made by an iOS Application released to the public?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.fir3net.com/Security/Concepts-and-Terminology/what-is-app-transport-security-ats.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, https is not strictly required, you can still include "http allowed" ATS exceptions in your info.plist.

Comment: you still have to give a motivation during the review process for each exception you add, so I won't say that is not strictly required

Comment: Really? I've never been asked for any of that.

Comment: yep, it's also stated in the App Store Review for ATS https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html

Comment: Indeed, as of Jan 2018, I tried, it's totally not required given the proper exceptions in the info.plist.